# Printing the even squares from an array into a separate array

Tags: c++

From the main function:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= squaresLength; i++)
    {
        cout << arraySquares[i] << endl;
    }
    cout<<endl;
```

The function definition:

```
   void evenSquares(int arrIn[], int lengthIn, int arrOut[], int& lengthOut)
{
    int i, j;
    for (i=0; i<lengthIn; i++)
    {
        if (((arrIn[i]*arrIn[i])%2)==0)
        {
            for (j=0; j<lengthIn; j++)
            {
                {
                    arrOut[j]=(arrIn[i]*arrIn[i]);
                }
            }

        }
    lengthOut=j;
    }

}
```

Output

```
25600
25600
25600
25600
25600
25600
25600
25600
25600
25600
25600
25600
25600
25600
25600
25600
25600
25600
25600
25600
25600
25600
25600
25600
25600
25600
25600
25600
25600
25600
25600
25600
25600
25600
25600
25600
25600
25600
25600
25600
25600
25600
25600
25600
25600
0
```

This function is a mess I know. It is supposed to calculate the square of each element of arrIn, and then store the even squares in arrOut, while setting the new value of lengthOut as the number of even squares in arrOut. Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Maybe you could clarify question by adding an example of the expected output?

Comment: Tip: the square of an odd number is always odd, the square of an even number is always even.

Answer (score 2):

This does not call for nested loops. You want to iterate over the input array and write items to the output array at a proportional rate, so only one loop is needed, along with some careful tracking of `arrOut`'s length.

Fortuitously, in place of `j` we can use `lengthOut` both a length and as the index at which to add elements to `arrOut`.

```
lengthOut = 0;

for (i = 0; i < lengthIn; i++)
{
    if ((arrIn[i] * arrIn[i]) % 2 == 0)
    {
        arrOut[lengthOut] = arrIn[i] * arrIn[i];
        lengthOut++;
    }
}
```

You might also improve this by eliminating the repeated calculation.

```
for (i = 0; i < lengthIn; i++)
{
    int square = arrIn[i] * arrIn[i];

    if (square % 2 == 0)
    {
        arrOut[lengthOut] = square;
        lengthOut++;
    }
}
```

Also, the first `for` loop suffers from an off-by-one error: `<=` should be `<`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < squaresLength; i++)
{
    cout << arraySquares[i] << endl;
}
```

Comment: You beat me, I was in the middle of just about this same answer when the orange box showedd up.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that in the first for cycle, every time you find an even square, you fill arrOut with lenghtIn copies of `arrIn[i]*arrIn[i]`. Note that `i` is not changing in the second for.
a correct code would be

```
int i,j,square;
j = 0;
for (i=0; i<lenghtIn; i++) {
    square = arrIn[i]*arrIn[i];
    if (square%2==0)
        arrOut[j++] = square;
}
lenghtOut = j;
```